# How to simulate a BLE device using a Nordic BLE stick so that it is discovered by an app

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Here's the setup, I have an Android app that discovers BLE devices, and to do some test automation I'd like to write a program that simulates, mocks,  one or several BLE devices.
I have a Nordic BLE USB stick (PCA10031), and thought I'd use that, since the actual device uses a Nordic BLE chip as well.
This is a broad "question" but I'm not sure how to start. It doesn't seem to be any JAVA or Python APIs, how do I mock a device with this setup?

Thanks to all who read my clumsy question

Comment: You are right it is broad question. First start reading books, tutorials and then try to do something. When you are stuck with concrete problem you can ask here.

Comment: Since you have a Nordic devkit, you need to use their SDK and a supported development environment (Keil, Segger studio etc.). You need to follow the same flow as creating a Nordic BLE peripheral. The only difference is that you already know exactly what services you should put in your GATT DB.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question completly.
Can you be more precise? I assume you want to write your own app to communicate on BLE with the Stick in server role? What's you target from which you want to run your stick?

Comment: Hi, I don't want to write an app, I'd like to write a piece of code that acts like a BLE device, and communicates with android app that connects to BLE devices. For instance imagine something like a watch that keeps track of your movements, temperature, etc... this watch is equipped with a Nordic BLE chip, and collects all this information that you can then view on an android app via BLE. Now What I wanna do is create a simulated program that "acts" like this watch and communicate with BLE via a Nordic USB stick, so that I can launch tests automatically.So I guess the stick would be the target

Comment: Ok what about writing a C# application in Visual studio to use your dongle from your laptop. As far as I understand is that you only have the hardware and maybe the driver for your stick. So you have to configure it as a BLE sever.You don't need to provide a userinterface, this should work with a console program too.

Comment: Yes that's about right, the thing that bugs me to begin is that I don't how to "control" the dongle, do I need a specific Nordic API or can I do otherwise? Thank you for your answers, this is the first time I try to use BLE stuff, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: no problem, you're welcome.
I have used the Ble adapter within my laptop. So I guess you should iinstall the needed drivers and then you should be able to use it. If your Laptop has one internal Bluetooth adapter try to turn it off and check if your program will use it instead automatically. If not I guess there has to be a possibility to decide which adapter should be used from your application.